# Compatibility of a TStringList backup from old to newest versions

Tags: delphi, compatibility, delphi-2007, unicode-string, tstringlist

I have a backup system which uses a TStringList, but I code with an old Delphi (Ansi strings).

Basically I have this when I save:

```
...
MyStringList.SaveToStream(Str);
StrSz := Str.Size;
MyBackupStream.Write(StrSz, SizeOf(Integer));
MyBackupStream.Write(Str.Memory^, StrSz);
...
```

And When I reload:

```
...
MyBackupStream.Read(StrSz, SizeOf(Integer));
Str.SetSize(StrSz);
MyBackupStream.Read(Str.Memory^, StrSz);
MyStringList.SetText := PChar( Str.Memory);
...
```

I use this sequential ( size + datasize bytes, then size + datasize bytes, etc) system for various component backup. In fact some stuffs are always 'read from' or 'written to' before the stringlist backup (I mean there are some data before and after the StringList backup).

Am I introducing a big problem here ( in case I switch to a modern Delphi version) ?
Will the chunk still be castable in future delphi version ( in case I switch ?). Would it be necessary for me to write the string version in the backup header ?

Unfortunately I cannot test this. I think that if I least I write the string encoding type in the header I'll be able to cast it in the right way later, whatever is the Delphi version, won't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MyStringList.LoadFromStream(Str)` instead of `MyStringList.Text := PChar( Str.Memory)`.

First, your `TStream` data is not null-terminated, but using `PChar` the way you are requires a null terminator (you can use `SetString()` with a string variable to get around that).

Second, starting in D2009, `String` is now `UnicodeString` instead of `AnsiString` and `PChar` is now `PWideChar` instead of `PAnsiChar`. Your `TStream` data is Ansi instead of Unicode (even in D2009+ because `SaveToStream()` defaults to using `TEncoding.Default`, which is Ansi, for encoding the stream data), so casting the data to `PWideChar` will assign garbage to your `TStringList`.

In all versions, you should be using `LoadFromStream()`, but if you want to stick with setting the `Text` property then you need to do it like this, which works in all versions:

```
var
  ...
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  ...
  MyBackupStream.ReadBuffer(StrSz, SizeOf(Integer));
  Str.SetSize(StrSz);
  if StrSz > 0 then MyBackupStream.ReadBuffer(Str.Memory^, StrSz);
  SetString(S, PAnsiChar(Str.Memory), StrSz);
  MyStringList.Text := String(S);
  ...
end;
```

Or this:

```
var
  ...
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  ...
  MyBackupStream.ReadBuffer(StrSz, SizeOf(Integer));
  if StrSz > 0 then begin
    SetLength(S, StrSz);
    MyBackupStream.ReadBuffer(S[1], StrSz);
  end;
  MyStringList.Text := String(S);
  ...
end;
```

Or this:

```
var
  ...
  Str: TStringStream;
begin
  ...
  Str := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    MyBackupStream.ReadBuffer(StrSz, SizeOf(Integer));
    if StrSz > 0 then Str.CopyFrom(MyBackupStream, StrSz);
    MyStringList.Text := Str.DataString;
  finally
    Str.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Lastly, you should consider changing your stream data to use UTF-8 instead of Ansi for even better future compatibility. Both `SaveToStream()` and `LoadFromStream()` have an optional `TEncoding` parameter in D2009+, and UTF-8 is a lossless Unicode encoding whereas Ansi can loss data during Ansi/Unicode conversions. If your existing data is ASCII (no `AnsiChar` characters above #127), then UTF-8 is 100% backwards compatible with ASCII. But if the data is Ansi instead (has `AnsiChar` characters above #127), then you are best off changing your stream format in some way (add a header/version, etc) so you can differentiate between older and newer formats, then you can load older formats using Ansi, and save/load newer formats using Unicode/UTF-8.

Comment: When I use loadfromstream I get AV. I've noticed this in a previous project, for me the only way to cast data saved with a TStringList.SaveToStream is to cast saved data as a string as done in my example. I know this is strange but I cannot do it in another way...

Comment: An AV means you are accessing invalid memory. Either the TStringList pointer or the TStream pointer is invalid. LoadFromStream() works just fine when used correctly. I've never had an AV with it, in any version. If you MUST cast, then you need to do it safer than what you showed earlier. What you showed is NOT safe.  It accesses surrounding memory that does not belong to the TStream.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted, but more to close the topic. In my backup stream I have a version number. Even if nobody explicitely told me here that I will be able to cast old data in a newest version of the software, I think it's ok. But you put the emphasis on the way I reload the strings. For me it was allright...I was not expecting a remark about this...

Comment: What you have shown will NOT work as-is in D2009+ because of the change in `PChar` from `PAnsiChar` to `PWideChar`. I will append my answer with an example that will work in all versions.

Comment: @az01 LoadFromStream presumably fails because it reads to the end of the stream and then the rest of the code tries to read beyond that. But this file format is incredibly brittle. You really should consider using a more advanced format, e.g. XML or YAML. Such formats make light of versioning issues.

Comment: @David: Yes, `LoadFromStream()` reads to the end of a stream. That is not a problem in az01's case, though, as his `Str` variable is a separate stream that holds just the single string that is copied from the source stream. That is not what is causing his AV problems (unless his stream pointer is invalid).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. I remember, several years ago, I finished a similar task as you did. I had two sections for each chuck of data: header and content. Header contained information like starting address and length of the chunk. The content part contained actual data. This approach had never had any problem. In your case, the header only contained the size of the block. As to the version number of string, I recommend you to do so as, based on the release road of Delphi, it is very common that new releases are not backward compatible with old releases. Even if you don't have to use the version number later, it doesn't harm.